# MySQL Driver not loaded on Qt

Tags: mysql, qt, database-connection

Trying to connect to MySQL using

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

gives me the

**Driver not loaded error**

Reading the other questions and answers did not help me because they have qt4 instead of 5 that I am using, and they had to build the drivers themselves. I do have the drivers though

[image: qtdrivers]

And I also did load the path in the pro file here

[image: qtprofile]

So why is this happening? Should I try and compile the drivers myself as suggested in some other questions?

**EDIT**

I also did make sure to use MySQL 32bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debug Mode on development machine the Qt-Framework Installation is enough.

In Release Mode you will have to provide the required driver in the sqldrivers-folder located in your working directory: `$(wcd)/sqldrivers/*`

Edit:
Check output of: QSqlDatabase::drivers () Eventually rebuild sql drivers for your system using $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/mysql.pro.

Also try adding mysql-client-library to your working directory directly or setting up a library path to look for. It is not enough to add `INCLUDEPATH` / `LIB` in pro file, since this is for compile/link time only. During runtime the executable looks in the known places (typical windows: $WINDIR/system32/;$PATH;...)

Comment: I am indeed in debug mode but the Could not load driver error is there still.

Comment: Check output of: ``QSqlDatabase::drivers ()`` Eventually rebuild sql drivers for your system using ``$QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/mysql.pro``. Also try adding mysql-client-library to your working directory directly or setting up a library path to look for.

Comment: I thought I had set the path (in the .pro file). Anyway your third suggestion seems to be working. I copied libmysql and libmysqld into Qt>bin directory and I had a successful connection. Can you please update you answer accordingly. Also what if I wanted to make this work on iOS should I copy the respective libraries from MySQL for iOS?

Comment: You would have to include drivers for ios in the app-package or contacting native ios-built in query module.

Comment: There is also one more thing, just out of curiosity. Why after running the command you suggested (QSqlDatabase::drivers()) it reported that i did have MYSQL, and yet it did not work out of the box and I had to manually copy the ell files?

Comment: The mysql-driver for qt still requires to find the mysql-dll during runtime, since this is no static built driver

Comment: I see, thats why some answers on similar question suggested to rebuild Qt with the MySql drivers. Thanks.